# What is the unit for resonant frequency?

Tags: frequency

What is the unit for resonant frequency? where \$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$? Is it just \$HF^{-1}\$?

Comment: Note: Capacitance has units "F," not "C."

Comment: There is no "resonant frequency", there is only "resonance frequency":  http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/misc/resonance.html

Comment: @AlfredCentauri except that 'resonant' does not apply to the frequency, but to the construct which is resonating - it is the 'frequency at which the construct is resonant', as such, the 'resonant frequency [of the construct]' is perfectly valid and correct. Also, as a side note, our language evolves through the acceptance of idioms which become common usage. Try insisting that no-one calls a 'vacuum cleaner' a 'Hoover'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the simplest way possible:

L is in [henries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_%28unit%29) (H) - \$\Omega \cdot s\$.

C is in [farads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad#Definition) (F) - \$\dfrac{s}{\Omega}\$

Multiply both and you have \$s^2\$. Take the square root, you have \$s\$. Invert it, you have \$\dfrac{1}{s}\$, that is, \$\frac{rad}{s}\$.

If the expression is written as \$\omega_0 = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$ the resonant frequency is in hertz.

Comment: It's actually rad/sec, you need to add an extra factor of 2pi to get to Hz.

Comment: yes, rad/s, thanks thats what i initially thought

Comment: It's rad per second, but in dimensional analysis radians are the same as no unit at all because a radian is the ratio of two lengths.

Comment: But dimensional analysis doesn't tell the whole story, it would for example let you confuse torque with energy. Also compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian

Answer (score 2):

From Wiki:

\$H = \Omega s\$ ([Wikipedia entry for Henry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_%28unit%29))

\$F = \dfrac{s}{\Omega}\$ ([Wikipedia entry for Farad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farad))

Thus:

\$\dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{HF} } = \dfrac{1}{s} =\$ Hz, as expected for a frequency

Answer (score 2):

\$ \omega \$ is "angular frequency" in \$ \frac{rad}{s} \$,

\$ f\$ is natural frequency AKA "frequency" in \$ Hz \$

So your title has an inherent conflict in it, you ask for frequency but talk about \$ \omega \$.

Also Radians are dimensionless so the rad in \$ \frac{rad}{s} \$ is a place holder for a scaling factor.